# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in java script function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Here is my code behind code. 
Whenever I pass some amount of data to **LoadPivot** this method code works fine but whenever I pass full data to this method its giving me error.

My Json string length which I am trying to pass is **10666492**

So is there any max character we can pass to java script method ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataSet JsonDataset = PivotDataset;
   String JsonConfig = PivotConfig;
   String jsonDS = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((JsonDataset.Tables[0]));


   //Facing Problem Here.
   jsonDS variable has huge data due to that whenever I pass some amount of data to this variable it works.
   but whenever i pass all the data to the variable this is giving me error.        
   "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list."

   String script = "window.onload = function() { LoadPivot('" + jsonDS + "','" + JsonConfig + "'); };";   

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "LoadPivot", script, true);
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `script` when the issue occurs?

Comment: your `jsonDS` or your `JsonConfig` seem to be invalid

Comment: @mjwills 10666492 is length of the string

Comment: these are more than 10 Million characters in that string

Comment: I didnt unerstood "Quite the JS payload" means ?

Comment: I mean it surprises me that you have a 10MB payload that you are serving up to your customers.

Answer (score 0):

As per the @mjwills 's comment I have checked my script & actual problem was my data which I was passing to javascript function.

Thanks for your suggestion @mjwills

The data i was getting in the **jsonDS** variable was containing **" "** in the data so my **JSON** object was not creating properly.

```
So conclusion is there was not a character length problem. 
it was invalid data which was causing the problem.
```